# Viewpager fragment reference to new copy after activity restore

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, activity-lifecycle

When my activity containing `viewpager` is killed by system in background and then restores its state, `fragments` are correctly created and `viewpager` `adapter` can also point to them correctly. 
But when I get a `fragment` reference and try to access its fields, they are all `null` (checked by using breakpoint).
I checked this by placing breakpoints in fragment `onCreateView()` and in my activity button's `clickListener`.

```
((WelcomeFragment)homeActivityFragmentPageAdapter.getItem(POSITION_HOME)).setdata(myData);
```

Now this method will through `null pointer` exception since `setdata(data)` is internally accessing `arraylist` field of `fragment`.

This creates a problem for me since, my activity has to continuously feed network data to the `fragment` by calling its public method (as suggested by documentation).

How to insure that after state restored; correct instance is pointed in my activity.

Comment: The fragment is managed by the Viewpager so your Activity should communicates with the ViewPager adapter, not the Fragment directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `instantiateItem` adapter method instead `getItem`.

```
((WelcomeFragment)homeActivityFragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, POSITION_HOME)).setdata(myData);
```

Method `getItem` is overrided method, and common use is creation of child fragments.

**EDIT:**

In case of the question's scenario, you also need to store the state of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` manually:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      savedInstanceState
        .putParcelable("pages",homeActivityFragmentPageAdapter.saveState());
      super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Then you can retrieve the state in oncreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            homeActivityFragmentPageAdapter.restoreState(savedInstanceState.getParcelable("pages"),this.getClassLoader());
            welcomeFragment = (WelcomeFragment) homeActivityFragmentPageAdapter.instantiateItem(mViewPager, POSITION_HOME);

        }
        else { //simply create a new instance here}

        homeActivityFragmentPageAdapter.addFragmentToAdapter(welcomeFragment);
        homeActivityFragmentPageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: thanks this worked. There is one more addition in my case, you need to save the state of adapter manually in `onSaveInstanceState` method and then while setting viewpager in oncreate retrieve state if present, instead of creating new instance of fragment.